# Display keycloak Password policy on Password page or registration page

Tags: keycloak

Is there any way to dynamically display the password policy info on the
Password page? i.e. show the password policy that is configured for the realm and not just hardcoded into the Theme.
Currently the only time the user knows about the policy is if they submit a password and see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to access this information with the base Keycloak setup, so in case anyone comes here looking for something similar, I've put together an extension that provides the password policy settings, as well as the realm attributes.

https://github.com/jcputney/keycloak-theme-additional-info-extension